# Related List SOQL query

Tags: apex, soql

I have the following code working:

```
SELECT of_Loans__c, Id, ( SELECT id FROM Loans__r WHERE MtgPlanner_CRM_Status__c = 'Closed')  FROM Contact
```

After some time tinkering around, I was able to access the information of the loan related list (on the Contact page) using the '__r' extension. The above SOQL query does as I want it:

[image: Successful SOQL query]

However, I did this in a sandbox environment which may not have the same relationships between objects as I have in live.

A similar SOQL query (in live):

```
SELECT of_Closed_Loans__c, Id, ( SELECT id FROM Loans__r WHERE MtgPlanner_CRM__Status__c = 'Closed')  FROM Contact
```

renders the following error: 
didn't understand relationship 'Loans__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names

Both environments have Contacts with a related list to the Loan object; I do not know what might I need to tweak on the live env. to replicate the results of the successful first sandbox env.

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Comment: You should check the _child relationship name_ of your relationship field on `Loan__c` in your prod/live environment. Given your error, it's quite likely to be something other than `Loans`.

Comment: Specifically, since you're using Dev Workbench, go to Info > Standard & Custom Objects. Select Contact from the Object drop-down. Expand the Child Relationships folder, and scroll down to `Loan__c.[your contact lookup or M/D field on Loan]__c`, and expand that. The `relationshipName` will be shown there.

Comment: THANK YOU!!!!!!